# Telegram Bot API: How to avoid Integer overflow in updates id?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram bot api get updates function takes last update id as offest parameter. But update id is signed 32bit integer, so it is just 2147483647.
Currently my bot receiving update id 348691972. 
2147483647 is a small number, for example current China and India population is more then int 32.
What will happen when update id will overflow and how to avoid it? 
Is it some kind of problem 2000?

Comment: "signed 32bit integer" - where did you get that from? It's not [in the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates).

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api
"It is safe to use 32-bit signed integers for storing all Integer fields unless otherwise noted."

Comment: Well, I guess they'll add the note when the "limit" gets closer. I see no problem here.

Comment: I think they use some kinds of hashing solution. All updates will expire some time, so their ID can be expired with them, and can be reused. You don't need to worry about overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is improbable because update_id resets after about a week of inactivity period. The issue can appear if the ID starts near the max integer, but this behavior is unlikely. From API documentation:

> If there are no new updates for at least a week, then identifier of
> the next update will be chosen randomly instead of sequentially.

See more details at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update